# Issues Switching System to Python3 and Retargeting Pip

Tags: python, pip

I have a bit of a comprehensive issue and I'm having trouble finding a good concise answer, so if anyone could assist me I would appreciate it. I'm on Windows 7.

I have Python 2.7 and 3.7 on my computer. Here are my problems:

1. Python 2.7 is the default version opened. How do I change the default to 3.7?
2. Pip installs to this version. How I get Pip to change to install into 3.7?
3. Should I just uninstall Python 2.7? If so, what's the best way to go about it?

Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: On Windows 7, the OS does not rely on Python 2. Mac and Linux use Python 2 for some OS level activities, so uninstalling Py2 can cause issues. I think you should be good to go to uninstall legacy python, but see if you can get an answer from someone knowledgeable! What I do personally, is set up Py3 virtual environments, and then activate the environment to control which version of Py to target.

Comment: I wouldn't mess with the system Python. As @mgrollins suggested, just use virtual environments.

Comment: Thank you for your replies. I won't uninstall Python27. I will look into virtual environments. Will that also solve my pip issue?

Comment: Yes, as long as your virtual environment is activated, your python.exe and pip will be the ones you expect. Something like this `c:\>c:\Python35\python -m venv c:\path\to\myenv` [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html)